# Why does DropDownList return a wrong value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I'm working on an application which is written in ASP.NET MVC with C#.

I try to create a view where a `DropDownList` can be used to navigate the user to another page.

But when I try to select something it always returns the value `0`.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexModel viewModel)
{
    var selectedReportId = viewModel.Id;
    var selectedReportName = viewModel.ReportCode;
    ViewData["input"] = selectedReportId;
    if (selectedReportId == 0 || selectedReportName == "----Select----") {
        ViewData["boucle"] = "boucle 1";
        return View(); 
    }
    if (selectedReportId == 1 || selectedReportName == "Order") {
        ViewData["boucle"] = "boucle 2";
        return View(); 
    }
    if (selectedReportId == 2 || selectedReportName == "Stock") {
        ViewData["boucle"] = "boucle 3";
        return View(); 
    }
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Report choice";
}

<p><h2>Report choice</h2></p>
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReportCode, new SelectList(new WebApplication4.Models.IndexModel().GetReport(), "Id", "ReportCode"))
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Report choice")]
    public string ReportCode { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IndexModel> GetReport()
    {
        return new List<IndexModel>
        {
            new IndexModel() {Id = 0, ReportCode = "----Select----"},
            new IndexModel() {Id = 1, ReportCode = "Order"},
            new IndexModel() {Id = 2, ReportCode = "Stock"}
        };
    }
}
```

Sorry for my English, it is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I just added an int selectedId in my model and used it as the first parameter of DropDownList, and it works ! Hopping that it'll be usefull for someone